# Binary to string/string to binary

Tags: c#

I want to convert text into binary and after that, to try convert binary into string text.
How can i convert `tobin` back into text if it is already a string?

```
  private void iTalk_Button_12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ambiance_RichTextBox2.Text = tobin(ambiance_RichTextBox1.Text);

    }
    public string tobin(string inp)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char L in inp.ToCharArray())
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(L, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Oh, where is the part when You're cnverting Your string to binary ?

Comment: you can refer this http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/convert-string-to-binary-and-binary-to-string-in-c/ link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        private void iTalk_Button_12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ambiance_RichTextBox2.Text = BinaryToString(ambiance_RichTextBox1.Text);
           //use what u need: BinaryToString or StringToBinary.
        }
```

Convert String to Binary:

```
        public static string StringToBinary(string data)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char c in data.ToCharArray())
            {
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Convert Binary to String:

```
        public static string BinaryToString(string data)
        {
            List<Byte> byteList = new List<Byte>();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 8)
            {
                byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 8), 2));
            }

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray());
        }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this,

```
public static string BinaryToString(string data)
{
List<Byte> byteList = new List<Byte>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 8)
{
 byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 8), 2));
}

return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to binary

```
string s = "hai"; 

byte []arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
```

To convert binary to string

```
byte[] arr ;

string s =  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(arr);
```

Comment: How can i display byte []arr in my richTextBox? This- ambiance_RichTextBox2.Text = arr.ToString();  gives me just System.Byte[] message.

Comment: string s = "hai";

byte []arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);richTextBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr);

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are converting a char (which can be represented as a number) to its binary representation (this number is the ASCII number). But if you want to convert a string to binary, you should use an encoding. The encoding determines how the text is converted to binary.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "This is an example text.";

    Console.WriteLine(input);
    string asBin = ToBinary(input);
    Console.WriteLine(asBin);
    string asText = ToText(asBin);
    Console.WriteLine(asText);
}

static string ToBinary(string input, System.Text.Encoding encoding = null)
{
    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(input); // Convert the text to bytes using the encoding

    foreach (var b in bytes)
        builder.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')); //Convert the byte to its binary representation

    return builder.ToString();
}

static string ToText(string bytes, System.Text.Encoding encoding = null)
{
    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    var byteCount = 8;
    var byteArray = new byte[bytes.Length / 8]; // An array for the bytes
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length / byteCount; i++)
    {
        var subBytes = bytes.Substring(i * byteCount, byteCount); // Get a subpart of 8 bits
        var b = Convert.ToByte(subBytes.TrimStart('0'), 2); // Convert the subpart to a byte
        byteArray[i] = b; // Add the byte to the array
    }

    return encoding.GetString(byteArray); // Convert the array to text using the right encoding.
}
```

Now if you want to use ASCII encoding, you can call the functions as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(input);
string asBin = ToBinary(input, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
Console.WriteLine(asBin);
string asText = ToText(asBin, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
Console.WriteLine(asText);
```